# I am having problems with how an object appears to be shaded?

Tags: mesh, geometry

[image: Shading problem]
Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong. It looks horrible

Comment: Try in edit mode selecting all vertices, and hitting "recompute normals" in the toolshelf on the left?

Comment: Tried that before this picture was taken, it solved some problems but not all

Comment: Share the file, looks like you have some modifiers on it or some bad geometry.

Comment: Try triamgulating the mesh and then resting the normals. Ctrl + T,     Ctrl + N

Comment: Sounds to me like you have [non-manifold topology](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599), which makes it so the normals of some faces will always be inconsistent with neighboring faces.